# Datatables jquery duplicate the <tr> rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

It's the first time that I use Datatables tool and works perfectly, short and search.

However,In the original table, I have four results (`<tr>`) and now it have eight results, but shows four.

I don't know if the problem could be because creates two table rows "**odd**" and "**even**".

The tr contains a popup div when click it, and having "odd" and "even" makes that sometimes display up or down.

[image: Example]

How can I fix it?

In the top, we can see a normal table with **4 rows**,

In the button, we see the table with Datatable only shows 4 rows, but really there are 8 `<tr>` elements (4 "odd" and 4 "even").

I have reading and search information but I can't find any util information.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: I can't see how jQuery is relevant to this, but can you show us parts of the code that produce this table?

Comment: Check in `console` may be `odd/even` rows are `invisible/hidden`

Comment: It would help a lot to see the table HTML that is converted into a dataTable, it might have some clues.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos, datatables is a jQuery plugin

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks. That clears some dust off this case.

Comment: yes, lets see the markup  - the original table structure